# Clean-up of elements that are no longer referenced, and were never added to the document

Tags: javascript, dom

Suppose I create a new element:

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

Now, later on in the script, I remove any JS references to it.

```
canvas = null;
```

Does the canvas **element** itself still exist, taking memory?  Or will it be garbage collected like any other unreferenced object?  Note that I haven't actually added it to the document.

Comment: Setting a variable's value to null doesn't delete it. It will still exist and take memory as an empty variable.

Comment: @K.Daniek I'm asking about the element, not the `canvas` variable itself.  The `canvas` variable will get handled when it iself is dereferenced elsewhere, outside of this example.  Essentially, I'm wondering if there is anything special about element objects, vs. any other object in JS.

Comment: The canvas element basically gets deleted after setting canvas value to null. It won't take more memory than a single, empty variable. But be aware that I'm only a 335 rep random user.

Comment: @K.Daniek Rep doesn't matter, if that's the answer, post it as an answer!  Thanks.

Comment: Garbage collection depends on your js engine but if it has support, dereferencing it will help to make it collected.

Comment: It will be garbage collected.

Comment: The created element will be "garbage" and will be marked as such when it is unreachable by reassigning the `canvas` variable to `null`. It will still take up memory, until it is garbage collected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the `<canvas>` element itself still exist, taking memory? Or will it be garbage collected like any other unreferenced object?

Yes, it still exists for the time being. Yes, it will be garbage collected in due time.

Other posters seem to be slightly confused about the difference in GC behavior between the `canvas` **variable** and the `<canvas>` **element**. Variables are allocated on the stack, not the heap. They occupy some tiny amount of memory on the stack as long as they are in scope. They  remain in scope by virtue of being in the call chain. The memory they use is released when the function is exited and stack frame popped.

Elements, like other objects, are allocated on the heap, and subject to garbage collection. They are GC'd when no longer referenced. The `<canvas>` element could be made to be no longer referenced **either** by setting any variable referring to it to `null` or something else, **or** the (only) variable referring to it going out of scope.

There is of course one other case relating to memory management of variables, which is closures. A variable which is closed over continues to occupy (a tiny amount of) memory as long as the enclosed function is "in scope", in other words, something references it. The value of such a variable--be it a DOM element or an JS object or anything else--will not and cannot be GC'd until the function in the closure goes out of scope. Little example:

```
function a() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  return function() {
    console.log(div);
  };
}

function b() {
  const func = a();
}
```

When `b` is entered, storage is allocated on the stack for `func`. `a` is called, which creates the DOM element and returns the inner function. At this point, `div` remains allocated because it has been closed over and is referenced from within the inner function. The DOM element remains in the heap. Once `b` exits, the variable `func` is popped off the stack frame, meaning that nothing refers to the closure function any longer. That means that `div` is no longer in scope. That in turns means that the element is no longer referenced and will be GC'd (eventually).

Bottom line is that you don't need to worry about any of this. It just works, barring pathological cases or engine bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm aware of closures and what not, I just wasn't sure if `document.createElement` did anything weird with that element, attaching it to something somewhere out of my control preventing it from being collected later.

Comment: No, `document.createElement` does not do anything like that. If not referenced, it will be GC'd. Even adding an event handler to it will not change that--the event handler hangs off the element, so if the element is no longer referenced, both the element and its event handler will be GC's.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize `Take Heap Shot`, `Record Allocation Time`, `Record Allocation Profile` at `Profiles` tab at `DevTools` to determine the memory status of a variable.

See

- [How to detect the memory allocations that are triggering garbage collection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429647/how-to-detect-the-memory-allocations-that-are-triggering-garbage-collection-in-j/39430897#39430897)
- [Memory Terminology](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/memory-101)
- [How to Record Heap Snapshots](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots)

  > Uncover DOM leaks
  >
  > The heap profiler has the ability to reflect bidirectional
  >   dependencies between browser native objects (DOM nodes, CSS rules) and
  >   JavaScript objects. This helps to discover otherwise invisible leaks
  >   happening due to forgotten detached DOM subtrees floating around.
  >
  > DOM leaks can be bigger than you think. Consider the following sample - when is the #tree GC?
  >
  > ```
  >   var select = document.querySelector;
  >   var treeRef = select("#tree");
  >   var leafRef = select("#leaf");
  >   var body = select("body");
  >
  >   body.removeChild(treeRef);
  >
  >   //#tree can't be GC yet due to treeRef
  >   treeRef = null;
  >
  >   //#tree can't be GC yet due to indirect
  >   //reference from leafRef
  >
  >   leafRef = null;
  >   //#NOW can be #tree GC
  > ```
  >
  > `#leaf` maintains a reference to it's parent (parentNode) and recursively up to `#tree`, so only when leafRef is nullified is the
  >   WHOLE tree under `#tree` a candidate for GC.
- [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

If there are no other references to `canvas`, it should be garbage collected. You can be certain of this by checking heap snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a large caveat that not every implementation uses the same garbage collection algorithm because it hasn't been standardized.  Namely, older versions of IE.

Quoting the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Mark-and-sweep_algorithm):

> Internet Explorer 6 and 7 are known to have reference-counting garbage
>   collectors for DOM objects

However, most modern browsers use *mark-and-sweep* garbage collection:

> **As of 2012, all modern browsers ship a mark-and-sweep
>   garbage-collector**. All improvements made in the field of JavaScript
>   garbage collection (generational/incremental/concurrent/parallel
>   garbage collection) over the last few years are implementation
>   improvements of this algorithm, but not improvements over the garbage
>   collection algorithm itself nor its reduction of the definition of
>   when "an object is not needed anymore".

Mark-and-Sweep will remove an object when it is *unreachable*.  So, in your case, if you assign a new value to the `canvas` variable, your newly created element will be unreachable and be marked for garbage collection.  It may take up memory for a brief period of time, until the garbage collector runs.  Also, because you used `let` it may be garbage collected as soon as the [block scope it's located in](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) is no longer needed in memory.

Comment: Per [the spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createelement), `document.createElement('canvas')` will return an element object.  If you assign the `canvas` variable to `null` you are now pointing to a new "object" (null is a primitive).  Where does the element that was previous pointed to go? It is now [unreachable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226825/do-javascript-objects-inside-of-an-array-erase-from-the-memory-when-i-clear-the#answer-14226980) and thus is marked for garbage collection but the memory is not immediately freed.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, I can give you a worthy answer right now, because I've checked it out by myself. In your case, you have just made a new variable and set its value to `document.createElement('canvas')`.

Until you decide to append that variable into your DOM, it's nothing more than just a value stored inside a variable. And with setting the value to null, the variable is now being stored and takes memory as a normal, single, empty variable.

The situation would be quite contrary, if you would append it into your document. The element wouldn't just be deleted with setting the variable's value to null and then it would waste memory.

Comment: Well, he already said he is **not** adding it to the DOM. So in that case, are you saying it would be GC'd?

Comment: @torazaburo If we can call an empty, unused variable a garbage, then yes.