# Where in the HTML node tree are dynamically generated elements stored?

Tags: javascript, html

I dynamically create an element using the following line of code in JavaScript:

```
const element = document.createElement("img");
```

I am able to access and modify the properties of the element, so it clearly exists, but what I can't figure out is where it is stored in the HTML node tree.

`element.parentNode` and `element.previousSibling` both return `null`. Does anyone know where it is actually located?

Comment: I believe it is just in memory until you append it to an element in the tree

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you’re correct, you should make that an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating an element using [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), the element is only stored within memory and not accessessable with `element.children`, or similar methods/getters.

To actually get access to it, you need to append it to an element in the DOM tree. Using one of many of the DOM methods:

- [element.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [element.insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

Once done, you can then access the element as you normally would. With one of the many accessors `element.children`, `element.querySelector()`, etc.

You can however access items that haven't been inserted into the dom as long as you have reference to them. As you can see here the `div` never gets inserted, however, I can still access the child `span` from the `div`, but I can not access the `div` from the say the `documentElement` because it hasn't been added to the `documentElement`.

```js
let div = document.createElement('div')
let span = document.createElement('span')

div.appendChild(span)

// We can access the child from the div
// Since the span has been added to the div
// Returns "SPAN"
console.log(div.firstChild.tagName)

// We can not access the div from the document
// Since the div wasn't added to the document
// Returns "null"
console.log(document.querySelector('div'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! One more thing: since the new element is just stored in memory and not in any particular place in the node tree, how do you delete it? I'm not very familiar with garbage collection in JavaScript -- would I need to set the pointer to the element to null or will JavaScript automatically handle it?

Comment: It should be garbage collected automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006399/clean-up-of-elements-that-are-no-longer-referenced-and-were-never-added-to-the